# Результат функции SYS_CONTEXT с параметром BG_JOB_ID отличается от предыущих версий

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, совместимость, oracle19c

В выпусках *Oracle* БД до 19c функция `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','BG_JOB_ID')` возвращала идентификатор задания (колонка `user_jobs.job`), если она выполнялась в фоновом процессе. Что соответствовало [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SYS_CONTEXT.html#GUID-B9934A5D-D97B-4E51-B01B-80C76A5BD086):

> BG_JOB_ID
>   Job ID of the current session if it was established by an Oracle Database background process. Null if the session was not established by a background process.

Начиная с выпуска 19c, эта же функция возврашает совершенно непонятное число,
к которому нет никакого соответствия в колонке `user_jobs.job`.

```sql
create table joblog (jobid int, memo varchar2 (256));
var jobid number;
begin
    dbms_job.submit (:jobid, q'[
        begin 
            insert into joblog values (sys_context ('USERENV','BG_JOB_ID'), 'running'); 
        end;]');
end;
/
select job from user_jobs where job=:jobid;

       JOB
----------
        34

commit;

select * from joblog;

     JOBID MEMO
---------- ----------------
     73517 running
```

Это баг или новые функциональные возможности? Как теперь связать выполнение задачи в фоновом процессе с идентификатором задачи полученом при её запуске?

Пробовал связать через представления `v$Scheduler_Running_Jobs` и `dba_jobs_running`. Так можно, но не уверен, что правильно.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/57673696/6571020

Comment: раньше Oracle Co. более аккуратно относились к обратной совместимости... :)

Comment: @MaxU Согласен, пока не понятно, примут ли они это как баг или отнекуются -- _мы же уже тысячу раз писали, переходите на скедулер_.

Answer (score 3):

В документаци о поддержке API `DBMS_JOB` [к выпуску 19c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/support-for-DBMS_JOB.html#GUID-CC42E8DA-7203-449E-BCEA-8187ECC4BCDF) по сравнению с [18c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/support-for-DBMS_JOB.html#GUID-CC42E8DA-7203-449E-BCEA-8187ECC4BCDF) добавленно:

> Oracle continues to support the DBMS_JOB package. However, you must grant the CREATE JOB privilege to the database schemas that submit DBMS_JOB jobs.

То есть, потребуется дополнительная привилегия, которая до 19c была не нужна. Зачем?

```sql
18c> var jobid number;
exec dbms_job.submit (:jobid, 'begin null; end;')

18c> select job, what from user_jobs;

       JOB WHAT
---------- --------------------------------
        41 begin null; end;

18c> select job_name, job_action from user_scheduler_jobs;

no rows selected
```

То же самое в 19c даст:

```sql
19c> select job, what from user_jobs;

       JOB WHAT
---------- --------------------------------
        44 begin null; end;

19c> select job_name, job_action from user_scheduler_jobs;

JOB_NAME         JOB_ACTION
---------------- --------------------------------
DBMS_JOB$_44     begin null; end;
```

Видно, что начиная с выпуска 19c задания созданые со старым API `DBMS_JOB` будут неявно конвертированы в задания нового API `DBMS_SCHEDULER`, для которых собственно и необходима привилегия `CREATE JOB`.

---

Функция `sys_context ('USERENV','BG_JOB_ID')` теперь возвращает внутренний идентификатор для заданий (колонка `v$scheduler_running_jobs.job_id`), который больше не коррелирует с колонкой `user_jobs.job` статрого API и на момент создания задания неизвестен.

Пока баг не будет устранён, пока такое решение:

```
create or replace function getBgJobId return number is
begin
    for r in (
        select job_name, regexp_substr (job_name, '\d+$') jobid   
        from user_scheduler_running_jobs
        where session_id = sys_context ( 'userEnv', 'SID')
        and running_instance = sys_context ( 'userEnv', 'Instance')
        ) loop return r.jobid; end loop;
    return null;    
end getBgJobId;
/
exec dbms_job.submit (:jobid, q'[begin dbms_output.put_line ('getBgJobId()='||getBgJobId); end;]') 
commit;

select job_name, output 
from  user_scheduler_job_run_details 
where job_name = 'DBMS_JOB$_'||:jobid;

JOB_NAME         OUTPUT                          
---------------- --------------------------------
DBMS_JOB$_51     getBgJobId()=51
```